# (Spoiler) Are there different storylines, depending on my choices?

Tags: gods-will-be-watching

In the second chapter where Burden and Jack get interrogated there is the possbility of Jack dying. However, even if this happens, he will be part of the next chapter. Does this mean that the consequences within one chapter don't have any impact on the story? Or are there any decisions to make, which will affect the storyline/ending?

Answer (score 1):

There definitely can be differences if characters die.

Prime example is Marvin in mission 3 - if he dies, then you will not have him available to hunt for food in the next mission.

However, don't expect a whole new storyline, just some "Walking Dead-esque" variations.

Comment: So this means the game divides between actions which cause consequences and with actions that won't? Kinda weird, since I think Jack dying is a pretty big deal and then he just lives again..

Comment: You tell me. In fact, until now I didn't even know Jack would be 'revived', as I had never managed to get him killed.

Comment: Haha, well ok this means I am bad at getting interrogated. When he is chained up you just need to provoke them two times and he will get torn apart...